# What is "to which" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, which-what

In the following sentence,

> The main focus though for Zink at this stage appears to be getting
> OpenGL games running over Vulkan drivers **to which** desktop OpenGL is
> more common than GLES 3.2 but this is a great milestone to see anyhow
> and could help with some mobile-type GLES3 games/engines.

How is "to which" interpreted?
I thought it is Relational pronouns first. So "Desktop OpenGL is more common than GLES 3.2 to that Valkan driver." But here "to that Vaulkan driver" doesn't seem grammatically correct, nor I can interpret it.

FYI, the original quote comes from [here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OpenGL-ES-3.2-Zink).

Comment: It's not at all clear what the sentence means, so the role of _to which_ is unsettled.

Comment: I wouldn't lose sleep parsing it, since it's also a run-on sentence and has no punctuation besides the terminal period. My initial reading is that "too which" is a hasty substitute for "for which purpose" (which is a poorly considered substitute for a gosh dang period and new sentence once in a while).

Comment: The sentence is very poorly constructed in many ways and struggles to convey the information well. What I _think_ the writer means is that OpenGL is more commonly used or is more commonly compatible with Vulkan drivers than is GLES 3.2, but it's not very clear.

Comment: I looked up the Vulkan driver on the net and it seems that it is a _competitive replacement for_ OpenGL and not compatible with it at all. I have even less respect for the quoted passage now, not only is it poorly written but it seems to be factually inaccurate as well.